# Formula in Latex: How to use special symbols in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, underline

I want to write following formula in Latex:

[image: Formula]

The problem is the "i" underneath "x". It is not a regular fraction. It means that value "x" will be replaced with "i". How can I write this one in Latex?
Additionally, the underlines are longer than the regular one which is used by typing "_". How can I modify the lenght of the underline?

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
    \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} 
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amstext} 

    \begin{document}
    $\langle x\,\,\underline{\,\,\,}\rangle_{k}\,\,\langle \underline{\,\,}\,\,x \mapsto i\,\,\underline{\,\,\,}\rangle_{state}$
    \end{document}
```

Hopefully, you can help me.

## Edit:

Thanks for your help! I have copied your extension and pasted it into my align environment.

```
\begin{align}
\centerline{Computational rules}
\[
p[\tabbedShortunderstack{
\udash{l_1}&,&\udash{l_2}&,&\dots&,&\udash{l_n}\\
r_1        & & r_2       & &     & & r_n
}]
\]
\centerline{Structural rules}
\[
p[\tabbedShortunderstack{
\uddash{l_1}&,&\uddash{l_2}&,&\dots&,&\uddash{l_n}\\
r_1         & & r_2        & &     & & r_n
}]
\]
\end{align}
```

If I try to run it, process stops with following error:

```
Bad math environment delimiter. \end{align}
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have so far ...

Comment: Welcome! TikZ... do your work!!

Comment: I have edited my first post. There is the code.

Comment: @user2379123 Can you undelete your previous question?

Comment: Seeing your deleted comment (that was given as an answer), I have provided a supplement to my answer to provide dashed lines.  I am not sure your gist of "not predefining any commands."  This is the purpose of macros, to save on typing.  One could always take the macro and replace it with definition of the macro...but why?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one idea.  In the MWE, you can adjust the `.7em` specification to change the size of both the underscore and the `\mygap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amssymb}
\stackMath
\newcommand\udash[2][\hrulefill]{\stackunder{#2}{\makebox[.7em]{#1}}}
\newcommand\mygap{\udash[]{}}
\begin{document}
\[
\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
  \udash{x}&\mygap&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k 
  \langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\mygap\udash{}\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

Seeing the OP's deleted answer, I have extended the result to include line dashing.  Also, here, `\udash` and `\uddash` will extend to the width of the argument (plus a little buffer), but with a minimum width of `.7em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amssymb}
\stackMath
\newlength\replength
\newcommand\ruleht{0pt}% ELEVATION OF RULE
\newcommand\repfrac{.6}% SOLID FRACTION OF DASH LINE [0->1] (USE 1 FOR SOLID)
\replength=.2em\relax% PERIOD OF DASHED RULE
\newcommand\rulewidth{.4pt}% THICKNESS OF RULE
\newcommand\drulefill{\leavevmode\dashfill\hfil%
  \kern\dimexpr\repfrac\replength-\replength\relax}
\newcommand\dashfill[1][\repfrac]{\cleaders\hbox to \replength{%
  \smash{\rule[\ruleht]{\repfrac\replength}{\rulewidth}}}\hfill}

\newcommand\udash[2][\hrulefill]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\stackon{\kern.7em}{\,#2\,}}%
  \stackunder{#2}{\makebox[\wd0]{#1}}}
\newcommand\uddash[1]{\udash[\drulefill]{#1}}
\newcommand\mygap{\hspace{.7em}}
\begin{document}
\[
\langle\tabbedShortunderstack{
  \udash{x}&\mygap&\udash{}\\ i&&}\rangle_k 
  \langle\udash{}\mygap x \mapsto i\mygap\udash{}\rangle_{\mathrm{state}}
\]
\centerline{Computational rules}
\[
 p[\tabbedShortunderstack{
   \udash{l_1}&,&\udash{l_2}&,&\dots&,&\udash{l_n}\\
   r_1        & & r_2       & &     & & r_n
 }]
\]
\centerline{Structural rules}
\[
 p[\tabbedShortunderstack{
   \uddash{l_1}&,&\uddash{l_2}&,&\dots&,&\uddash{l_n}\\
   r_1         & & r_2        & &     & & r_n
 }]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]